# R DBI new netezza interface

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a DBI compliant interface for Netezza using the newer odbc interface.

Following my attempt:

```
#' Driver for Netezza Db
#' @keywords internal
#' @export
#' @import DBI
#' @import methods
setClass('NetezzaDriver', contains = 'DBIDriver')
#### -------------------------------------------------------------
#' @export
Netezza <- function() {
  new("NetezzaDriver")
}
#### -------------------------------------------------------------
#' Netezza connection class
#' @export
#' @keywords internal
setClass("NetezzaConnection",
         contains = "DBIConnection",
         slots = list(server = 'character',
                      database = 'character',
                      uid = 'character',
                      pwd = 'character',
                      port = 'numeric')
)
#### -------------------------------------------------------------
#' dbConnect method for NetezzaDriver
#' @param drv An object created by \code{Netezza()}
#' @rdname Netezza
#' @importFrom  odbc dbConnect
#' @export
setMethod("dbConnect", "NetezzaDriver",
          function(drv, server ,database ,uid ,pwd ,port = 5480, ...) {
            con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                             driver = drv,
                             server = server,
                             database = database,
                             uid = uid,
                             pwd = pwd,
                             port = port, ...)

            new("NetezzaConnection",
                server = server,
                database = database,
                uid = uid,
                pwd = pwd,
                port = port,
                ptr = ptr)
          })
```

When I try to use dbConnect ...

```
db <- dbConnect(RNetezza::Netezza(),
                 drv = 'Simba',
                 server = '192.168.69.212',
                 database = 'NYCFLIGHTS',
                 uid = 'userR',
                 pwd = 'userR',
                 port = 5480)
```

I get

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"
```

Note that:

```
db <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 driver = 'Simba',
                 server = '192.168.69.212',
                 database = 'NYCFLIGHTS',
                 uid = 'userR',
                 pwd = 'userR',
                 port = 5480)
```

works correctly ...

I really cannot figure out what could be missing

Thanks in advance for any help